# Modular Tour of Heroes Angular 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng-bootstrap

I went through the tour of heroes tutorials on angular and i wanted to try to do something a bit different. So i am on the [Services tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html), before routing.

Project Source can be found on my linked [public Git repository](https://github.com/JordanGS/angular2/tree/master/projects/modularhero).

The goal is to use the [ng-bootstrap modal component](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal) to display hero details and allow for edits which will persist.

**How to run the Git Project**

`$ npm install`

`$ npm start`

The project will compile and open on `localhost:4200`

**Code Snippets**

**app.component.ts**: loops through a list of heros and calls `hero-modal` for each.

```
  <h2>My Heroes</h2>
  <ul>
    <li style="list-style: none; padding-top: 3px;" *ngFor="let hero of heroes" 
      [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
      (click)="onSelect(hero)">
      <hero-modal [hero]="hero"></hero-modal>
      <!--<span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}-->
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**hero-modal.component.html**: A button gets created for each hero which when pressed will display the hero details.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary text-left" style="width:300px; align:left;" (click)="open()"><i class="fa fa-id-card-o fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;{{hero.name}}&nbsp;</button>
```

**hero-modal.content.html**: The information for each specific hero that was passed in. Here the information can be changed as well to be persisted globally. (**BROKEN**)

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">Hi there!</h4>
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Hero => {{name}}!</p>
  <div *ngIf="hero">
    <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
    <div>
      <label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
    <div>
      <label>name: </label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
</div>
```

**Hero-modal.component.ts**: This class is a near copy of modal tutorial from the ng-bootstrap site linked above. I think the problem is in here but **(1)** i'm not sure how to pass the information in at this point. And **(2)** Once a data change is made in the modal, i'm not sure how to get it out to persist globally.

```
import {Component, Input, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import {NgbModal, NgbActiveModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'hero-modal-content',
  templateUrl: './hero-modal-content.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: ['./hero-modal-content.css'] /** This contains the theme for the window **/
})
export class HeroModalContent {
  @Input() name;

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'hero-modal',
  templateUrl: './hero-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['hero-modal.component.css', '../app.component.css']
})
export class HeroModalComponent {
  @Input() hero: Hero;
  closeResult: string;
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(HeroModalContent, { windowClass: 'dark-modal' });
    modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'FR';
    modalRef.result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return  `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, how do i get the modal to globally persist the settings, not just now but if they close the browser, the settings will persist as well. Name changes, etc. I don't have a database to use nor would i want one. Each user should have a unique experience. Cookies maybe? If so, how would i incorporate cookies into this? I hope this update has clarified my question, if not. Please let me know what else i can do to make it cleared. Thank you.

Current screenshot:

[image]

Comment: **The code is in the git repository**. Check it out if you're willing to help (it was **linked above**). It's a lot easier for me to upload a project and let you be able to compile it in 5 seconds to see. Than to spam the entire post with 3 classes+ I'm trying to figure out how to have settings persist from a modal

Comment: @Claies **how do you persist settings from a modal**, if i knew where the issue was, i wouldn't have uploaded a repository. This keeps things cleaner as well.

Comment: @Claies and i appreciate your help, but i don't know where the problem is. I don't know how to get the information from the modal back to the parent. I've spent the last day and half trying to research. If i could have been clearer, i would have been. It's not a school project. I'm just trying to learn angular 2. Maybe the best thing would be to take a class or something. :/ Thanks for trying.

Comment: @Claies okay, i'll add some screenshots and snippets of where i think the issue is, give me a couple minutes please

Comment: @Claies I wrote **snippets** also

Comment: @Claies no, i asked two questions. 1) which involves code, as you can see from the screenshot. I'm not able to transfer the data to the modal for some reason. I'm having a hard time figuring out why. I think there's an issue with my hero-modal.component.ts and 2) was what is a good way to make the data persist. :)